# How do GFX Designers make these type of designs?

Tags: software-recommendation, illustration, tools, resource-recommendations, style

What is involved in creating the following images? What programs and resources would guide an average-user/newbie to being able to produce images similiar to these?

I would greatly appreciate any URLs to tutorials on this kind of work, or tutorials for 'foundations' that lead to this kind of work. I apologize for the broad potential of responses.

Here's two examples of works which I'd like to learn how to create my own images of a similar style:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Luciano for the edit. I was lost with the tags and had no idea what to put. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are a beginner you need time to grasp a few things, but don't worry sir! I'll tell you the process and the rest you will do by practice.

Here is the Complete Process:

1. The above images you posted are all digital painting designs
2. First everything starts with the sketch.

   I recommend you buying a tablet or sketch papers if you want to start now, The cheap tablet I can recommend is Huion 12', one which will help your process even faster.
3. You must have some painting or designing skills (However again practice makes the man perfect).
4. Start sketching your ideas and don't worry if it's rough.
5. Here is the important part: Which software? (Well, I highly recommend using the Adobe Illustrator or Photoshop which are my personal favourite) Let's start with Illustrator then.
6. After sketching your ideas you need to make separate layers for each design you are making (for example: sketch, line art, colors, shadows and effects).

   First, make a sketch.

   Second, make line art using the Pen Tool or Brush Tool (Make sure it's clean).

   Third, add colors from the Live Paint Bucket Tool.

   Fourth, add effects and shadows.

   The last, which is the most important, is making all images super attractive. Use Photoshop to edit it as a photo. Just add some effects. You can also use some plugins for auto effects and more.

Well, there are lots of videos for you to get started, like making line art and sketching but here I can only give you an idea.

Hope that helps. Please let me know and ask anything you like.

Comment: Please stop self promoting your blog.

Comment: @Saqib Self promotion that isn't directly relevant to the answer (just being about design isn't) is frowned upon and will be seen as spam.

Comment: Guys it's not spam! I specifically asked for links to tutorials and any resources. This is a very HQ answer that's helped me greatly so the 'self-promoting' is a direct response to my question which I asked for!

Saqib, I think you've removed the link so can you please post it here in the comments or message me privately

And thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Well, no problem and sorry if its look spam, I thought I gave a good answer but feeling strange and disheartened. Leaving this website as I dont think I belong to this community and Really again I am not spammer Hope you guys understand. Thank You!